# How do you turn structured data into an observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a web api returning some structured data.

```
{
    i: {
        f: [...],
        a: val,
        b: val
    },
    a: [...],
    b: [...],
    c: [...]
}
```

I am returning this to an angular 6 application - I assume using Observables and rxjs. All the examples I see with observables assume an array that is cast to the observable. However, this data is structured and contains some sub-arrays within the structure.

I'm new to Angular so I'm looking for some direction if possible.

Comment: maybe you can provide an example of the structured data and your desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

service:

```
import {
    HttpClient,
    HttpErrorResponse,
    HttpEvent,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpInterceptor,
    HttpRequest,
    HttpHeaders
} from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient,
        ) {
    }

    /**
     * This method is use for send GET http Request to API.
     * @param url - Additional request URL.
     * @param options  - Header(s) which will pass with particular request.
     */
    get(url: string, options?: any): Observable<any> {

        return this.httpClient.get(url, this.requestOptions(options))
    }





   /**
    * Request options.
    * @param headerOptions
    * @returns {RequestOptionsArgs}
    */
    private requestOptions(headerOptions?: any): any {
        options = {
                    headers: new HttpHeaders({
                        "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                    })
                }
             }
```

component.ts:

```
 myData: Array<any>;

    /**
     * This method is used to get  data
     */
    getFormData(filter) {

        this.requestURL = `your_url`;

         this.http.get(this.requestURL, options).subscribe(response => {

              this.myData = response as ArrayCast[]
              console.log(response)
            })
           ;
    }

export class ArrayCast{
  a: any;
  b: any;
  c: any;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, how do you get the data into your Angular application? By an http call?
Then you automaticly (with Angular5+ => HttpClient) will get an observable that contains the whole structure (with all nestings, with all arrays inside it).

```
this.http.get(url).subscribe( result => console.log(result));
```

If the get to this "url" will return your complex json, than you will get an observable that will emit exactly ONE Value. And this value will be your whole complex json.

A Observable can wrap everything. Primitives (number, string, boolean) or complex objects. For the observable it´s no difference.

You can also create an observable directly in your code (for example for testing purposes)

```
import {of} from 'rxjs/internal/observable/of';
of(myData);
```

There are multiple way´s to create observables (take a look at those examples [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/))

warm regards